# What does it mean to short circuit a transmission line stub at a specific frequency?

Tags: rf, transmission-line, microwave, mixer, transmission

I'm currently designing a  microwave FET mixer right now, and I have to short-circuit the FET's drain at LO frequency and its harmonics. I've checked the "stub" article in wiki, and it says that the resonant frequency of the stub is w0=pi*v/2*l. So i set the drain stub's length to this value at the software to short circuit it at the LO and its harmonics. It is enough for it, or should I adjust other parameters?
Or if it's completely the wrong way, how could i set it to became short cirtuit?

Comment: How did you implement it. You need to show this.

Comment: I try to design my mixer based on an example from a book( Stepehen A Maas: Nonlinear Microwave Circuits). It would be better if I could send a screenshot of this, but this textbox don"t allow it.The auothor implemented it in AWR microwave office.  The FET's drain is connected to a an Open microstrip line with end effect(MLEF) and parallel to that line, there is a simple microstrip line, and then a chip capacitor, because the output(the IF load) is connected to the drain. You can adjust the length and the width of the stub.

Comment: Short circuit means zero impedance. Stubs are one way to change impedances.